# Easily create a rectangle relative to node

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I have a node and I want to fill a rectangle that is `12pt` larger in vertical distance and `6pt` larger in horizontal distance.  I know that this works

```
\documentclass[10pt,convert={convertexe=magick,density=1000,outext=.png}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle] (a) at (0,0) {test};
\path (a.south west) +(-6pt,-3pt) coordinate (b);
\path (a.north east) +(6pt,3pt) coordinate (c);
\fill[opacity=0.3] (b) rectangle (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this is a very inefficient way to do it, as I have to define two additional coordinates.  Is there an easier way to achieve the same result, as this situation repeats several time through my document with different shapes, sizes etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to define the coordinates if you use `shift`, e.g. `([shift={(6pt, -3pt)}]a.south east)`. Another option is to use the `fit` library and set `inner xsep` and `inner ysep` separately, see code example below.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle] (a) at (0,0) {test};

% your method
\path (a.south west) +(-6pt,-3pt) coordinate (b);
\path (a.north east) +(6pt,3pt) coordinate (c);
\fill[opacity=0.3] (b) rectangle (c);

% using shift
\fill [blue, opacity=0.3] ([shift={(-6pt, 3pt)}]a.north west) rectangle ([shift={(6pt, -3pt)}]a.south east);

% fit node
\node [inner xsep=6pt, inner ysep=3pt, fill=red, opacity=0.3, fit=(a)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative valid for a node or for a more complex picture could be to use the `background rectangle`. You don't have to worry about coordinates, `TiKZ` does it for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!50}, 
    inner frame xsep=6pt, 
    inner frame ysep=3pt},
    show background rectangle]
    \node[draw] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    background rectangle/.style={fill=gray!50}, 
    inner frame xsep=6pt, 
    inner frame ysep=3pt,
    show background rectangle]
    \node[draw] (A) {Test};
    \node[draw, circle] (B) at (1,0) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looking from the pictures you shared, it seem there is the same border in x and y direction.

Comment: @Pygmalion `inner frame ?sep` must not be set inside the `background rectangle` style but outside.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for the comment. The mistake was due to a wrong lecture of manual section. I've corrected it.

Comment: @Pygmalion I've updated the answer. Thank you.